# mysql group by Select group select value for different rows of a column

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have below table.

> 

```
+----------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| src      | dst    | dstchannel        | linkedid          | uniqueid          | disposition |
+----------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| 98267859 | 820006 | SIP/8207-0002fbda | 1571884780.349482 | 1571884780.349482 | NO ANSWER   |
| 98267859 | 820006 | SIP/8208-0002fbdb | 1571884780.349482 | 1571884780.349482 | NO ANSWER   |
| 98267859 | 820006 | SIP/8209-0002fbdc | 1571884780.349482 | 1571884780.349482 | NO ANSWER   |
| 98267859 | 820006 | SIP/8210-0002fbdd | 1571884780.349482 | 1571884780.349482 | ANSWERED    |
| 31389779 | 820006 | SIP/8207-0002fbdf | 1571884804.349487 | 1571884804.349487 | NO ANSWER   |
| 31389779 | 820006 | SIP/8208-0002fbe0 | 1571884804.349487 | 1571884804.349487 | NO ANSWER   |
| 31389779 | 820006 | SIP/8209-0002fbe1 | 1571884804.349487 | 1571884804.349487 | NO ANSWER   |
| 31389779 | 820006 | SIP/8210-0002fbe2 | 1571884804.349487 | 1571884804.349487 | ANSWERED    |
| 93870557 | 820005 | SIP/8207-0002fbf8 | 1571885246.349518 | 1571885246.349518 | NO ANSWER   |
| 93870557 | 820005 | SIP/8208-0002fbf9 | 1571885246.349518 | 1571885246.349518 | NO ANSWER   |
| 93870557 | 820005 | SIP/8209-0002fbfa | 1571885246.349518 | 1571885246.349518 | NO ANSWER   |
| 93870557 | 820005 | SIP/8210-0002fbfb | 1571885246.349518 | 1571885246.349518 | ANSWERED    |
| 98174911 | 820006 | SIP/8207-0002fc03 | 1571885371.349528 | 1571885371.349528 | ANSWERED    |
| 98174911 | 820006 | SIP/8208-0002fc04 | 1571885371.349528 | 1571885371.349528 | NO ANSWER   |
| 98174911 | 820006 | SIP/8209-0002fc05 | 1571885371.349528 | 1571885371.349528 | NO ANSWER   |
| 98174911 | 820006 | SIP/8210-0002fc06 | 1571885371.349528 | 1571885371.349528 | NO ANSWER   |
| 96780172 | 820006 | SIP/8207-0002fc31 | 1571886738.349609 | 1571886738.349609 | NO ANSWER   |
| 96780172 | 820006 | SIP/8208-0002fc32 | 1571886738.349609 | 1571886738.349609 | NO ANSWER   |
| 96780172 | 820006 | SIP/8209-0002fc33 | 1571886738.349609 | 1571886738.349609 | NO ANSWER   |
| 96780172 | 820006 | SIP/8210-0002fc34 | 1571886738.349609 | 1571886738.349609 | ANSWERED    |
```

Here each record is in 4 rows, what i want is to query for each column such that select the record if it is answered else select the first row.

Below is my real query with other tables which i need to connect on certain conditions. It all works well except selecting the correct dstchannel if there is an answered call.

> 

```
SELECT cdr.uniqueid,extension, 
DATE_FORMAT(MAX(calldate),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS calldate, 
CASE WHEN src IN 
(8207,8208,8209,8210,64566556,64566556,64566556,64566556,820006,820005,'any value here') 
THEN cnum 
ELSE src END AS caller_id_number,
CASE WHEN dst NOT IN (SELECT grpnum FROM asterisk.ringgroups) 
THEN dst 
ELSE 
TRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(dstchannel,1,LOCATE("-",dstchannel,LENGTH(dstchannel)-8)-1),"SIP/",""))
END AS destination, 
TRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(dstchannel,1,LOCATE("-",dstchannel,LENGTH(dstchannel)-8)-1),"SIP/","")) AS dst,
CASE WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(disposition,",") LIKE "%ANSWERED%" THEN "Answered" ELSE "Abandoned" END AS disposition, 
MAX(billsec) AS billsec, (duration-billsec) AS ringtime, duration, 
CASE WHEN recordingfile!='' THEN recordingfile ELSE "No Data" END AS Recording, 
cnam AS CallerID FROM cdr LEFT 
JOIN asterisk.users 
ON cdr.dst=asterisk.users.extension OR
TRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(cdr.dstchannel,1,LOCATE("-",cdr.dstchannel,LENGTH(dstchannel)-8)-1),"SIP/","")) = asterisk.users.extension 
LEFT JOIN cel ON cel.linkedid = cdr.uniqueid 
WHERE dst IN (8207,8208,8209,8210,64566556,64566556,64566556,64566556,820006,820005) 
AND calldate BETWEEN '2019-10-24 00:00:00' AND '2019-10-25 23:59:59' AND disposition = 'Answered'
AND cdr.uniqueid = cel.linkedid GROUP BY cel.linkedid
```

And My results are as below

> 

```
+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+
|        DATE         |        Caller ID         |     FROM     |    TO    | Direction | Ring TIME | Duration |  Recording   |  STATUS   |
+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+
| 20-10-2019 10:24:47 | 96881508                 | 96881508     |     8207 | Inbound   |         0 |      150 | NO Recording | Answered  |
| 20-10-2019 11:07:40 | 97164881                 | 97164881     |     8207 | Inbound   |         0 |       89 | NO Recording | Answered  |
| 20-10-2019 11:31:55 | 97806791                 | 97806791     |     8207 | Inbound   |         0 |       38 | NO Recording | Answered  |
| 20-10-2019 11:40:49 | 92706696                 | 92706696     |     8207 | Inbound   |         0 |       75 | NO Recording | Answered  |
| 20-10-2019 11:49:23 | 8208 - Aramsa Sgd FD - 2 | 8208         | 92706696 | Outbound  |        14 |      105 |  Recording   | Answered  |
| 20-10-2019 11:53:19 | 8208 - Aramsa Sgd FD - 2 | 8208         | 92706696 | Outbound  |        36 |       24 |  Recording   | Answered  |
| 20-10-2019 12:16:50 | 8208 - Aramsa Sgd FD - 2 | 8208         | 81858355 | Outbound  |        20 |        0 |  Recording   | Abandoned |
| 20-10-2019 12:19:48 | 91825573                 | 91825573     |     8207 | Inbound   |         0 |       27 | NO Recording | Answered  |
| 20-10-2019 12:32:10 | 14159348690              | +14159348690 |     8207 | Inbound   |         0 |      149 | NO Recording | Answered  |
| 20-10-2019 12:50:07 | 8207 - Aramsa Sgd FD - 1 | 8207         | 81807285 | Outbound  |        57 |        0 |  Recording   | Abandoned |
| 20-10-2019 13:14:51 | 8207 - Aramsa Sgd FD - 1 | 8207         | 96788908 | Outbound  |        11 |       10 |  Recording   | Answered` |
+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: 'select the first row.' I don't see a way of establishing first other than possibly  dstchannel and I don't understand what that is?

Comment: the first row starts with SIP/8207 i think, at least this seems to be the pattern

Comment: @P.Salmon Actually all the records are same except if answered and the dstchannel, In result record I need the dstchannel for the answered one else any one.

Comment: @nbk  If there is an answered record at number 3 then How I can select dstchannel for that one.

Comment: 'If there is an answered record at number 3 then How I can select dstchannel for that one.' that's the easy bit where disposition = 'answered'

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes If I select single record  but I need to display the whole table on a grid and also if No one is answered then show a single record with dispostion as No answered and dstchannl of the second one. I tried many queries but No luck Can you help with a query.

Comment: To help clarify your requirement if would help if you added your expected outcome to the question.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have added my results and my query. If you still need  me to add more sample data I will add that too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that SIP/8207 is the lowest number as as far as i can tell from your data
So my suggestion is

```
Select * From tableA Where disposition = 'ANSWERED'
Union
SELECT * From tableA Where linkedid not  in 
  (Select linkedid From tableA Where disposition = 'ANSWERED') 
and dstchannel LIKE 'SIP/8207%';
```

This returns, because all where answered

```
src         dst     dstchannel          linkedid    uniqueid    disposition
98267859    820006  SIP/8210-0002fbdd   1571884780  1571884780  ANSWERED
31389779    820006  SIP/8210-0002fbe2   1571884804  1571884804  ANSWERED
93870557    820005  SIP/8210-0002fbfb   1571885246  1571885246  ANSWERED
98174911    820006  SIP/8207-0002fc03   1571885371  1571885371  ANSWERED
96780172    820006  SIP/8210-0002fc34   1571886738  1571886738  ANSWERED
```

If you have another pattern, please show a sample with no answering.

Comment: records are grouped by linkedid not src.  Is it possible to do it using group by linkedid and then using case statement  where dispostion is answered select dst from answered row else any one.

Comment: i changed my answer, and no grup by is only helpful if using when using https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html , and there is no need. Casee when is also not necessary, for your purposes union is the better option

Comment: Thanks and sorry I forget to mention that I don't have such specific value for dstchannel  to select unanswered calls and also there are cases where there are multiple answered calls.